# HttpClient auto-upload file to remote server

Tags: java, file-upload, upload, httpclient

I'am trying to convert many doc files via an online website, using HttpClient to emulate an Http request

`URI uri = new URI("http://www.docx2doc.com/convert/convert-file");`

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);


    reqEntity.addPart("email",new StringBody(""));
    reqEntity.addPart("input_type",new StringBody("doc"));
    reqEntity.addPart("output_type",new StringBody("html"));
    reqEntity.addPart("script",new StringBody("converters"));



    FileBody bin = new FileBody(
        new File("mydoc.docx"));
    reqEntity.addPart("input_file", bin );

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);`
```

all the parameters (email,output_type...) in the post are accepted by the server but not the file ...

how can I handle this ?

Thank You.

Comment: What does `all the parameters (email,output_type...) in the post are accepted by the server but not the file ...` mean? Does server return an error? What is the error?

Comment: When I analyse the response of the server it seems to take those parametres, but it gives me a BROWSE button to select the file, which means that the server do not take the file value.

Comment: The website seems to be an interactive server. They may not support programmatic access and may have checks to prevent that. if there are not captchas on the site you can use a sniffer with a browser to observer the interaction and mimic that in your program, including the browser type.